# How to attach token in a custom form field

Tags: forms, 8, tokens

I have a custom form in Drupal 8. I need to attach tokens for fields of my form. Basically I want to add "Browse tokens" option for each field of my form.

Answer (score 6):

`token.module` has various examples, for example this:

```
// Add the token tree UI.
$form['email']['token_tree'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'token_tree_link',
  '#token_types' => array('user'),
  '#show_restricted' => TRUE,
  '#weight' => 90,
);
```

This displays a link for tokens for the type user (and global tokens).

You can also use the `#element_validate` callback `token_element_validate` together with also adding `#token_types` to have it validated.

Comment: I am using '#theme' => 'token_tree_link',
      '#token_types' => array('user'),
      and i want to display only Users token not other tokens, What should i use? I have tried '#show_restricted' => TRUE,It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: As noted in @Calar's answer, limiting the options only to those defined by  `#token_types` can be achieved with `'#global_types' => FALSE,`

Answer (score 4):

This is a copy from the "token.module".

```
function token_theme() {
  $info['token_tree_link'] = [
    'variables' => [
    'token_types' => [],
    'global_types' => TRUE,
    'click_insert' => TRUE,
    'show_restricted' => FALSE,
    'show_nested' => FALSE,
    'recursion_limit' => 3,
    'text' => NULL,
    'options' => [],
  ],
  'file' => 'token.pages.inc',
  ];

  return $info;
}
```

To avoid displaying the "global tokens" you need:

```
'global_types' => FALSE,
```

Code as a render element (don't forget the #(!)):

```
// Add the token tree UI.
$form['email']['token_tree'] = array(
 '#theme' => 'token_tree_link',
 '#token_types' => array('user'),
 '#show_restricted' => TRUE,
 '#global_types' => FALSE,
 '#weight' => 90,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$form['token_help'] = [
  '#theme' => 'token_tree_link',
  '#token_types' => ['user'],
];
```

https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token